# How to preserve units with SASS computed variable?

Tags: sass

I try to create some relative font-size values that match "nearly" pixels sizes:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }

$font-10px: 1em/1.1em;
$font-11px: 1.1em/1.1em;
$font-12px: 12em/11em;

.x10 { font-size: $font-10px; }
.x11 { font-size: $font-11px; }
.x12 { font-size: $font-12px; }
```

However, the output of this sass snipet is:

```
.x10 {
  font-size: 0.90909;
}

.x11 {
  font-size: 1;
}

.x12 {
  font-size: 1.09091;
}
```

As you can see, the unit (`em`) has been stripped.

This results in a incorrect value.

How should I declare my variables to contains the correct unit?

Comment: Why would you do this... ever?  Every time someone uses `font-size: 62.5%` a kitten dies.

Comment: @cimmanon: actually, this rules is inherited from the hosting application, which is SharePoint. I don't control the rules on the higher tags (html, body, ...), but I control the css of the Widgets I'm adding.

Comment: But you do understand that `0.90909em != 10px`, right?  You're doing yourself and anyone else who reads this code a disservice by labeling them as such.  If you really want 10px, *just use 10px*.

Comment: @cimmanon: I do understand. The customer think on pixels (due to the PhotoShop provided by its web agency), but we think in em to prepare the application for accessibility ♿. And most of all, the hosting application uses 1.1em for the body font-size. This could lead to weird look if the whole apps resize and not the widget

Comment: @cimmanon: actually, my math was wrong. I have to divide by 13 and not 11 to approach the sizes in pixels.

Comment: You're missing the point here.  It doesn't matter what your math is, there will never be an instance where you can safely treat `Xem == 10px` because the base font-size is not guaranteed to be 16px.  By converting between px and em this way, you aren't thinking in terms of em, you're still thinking in terms of px.  If accessibility actually was a concern for you, you wouldn't be using 65.2% for your font-size in the first place, you'd be respecting the user's chosen font-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing one length by another length always results in the unit being removed if the lengths are using the same units.  So your options are:

- Divide using one length and one integer: `1.1em / 1.1`
- Multiply the unit back on afterwards:  `1.1em / 1.1em * 1em`
- Don't use division at all: `1em`

Answer (score 0):

Add PX to the end of your variable and surround the variable with #{ }. This is known as [interpolation #{ }](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) and treats the variable as plain css. Interpolation also helps to remove any spaces between the number and unit of measurement:

```
$base-font-size: 16;
body  { font-size: (62.5% * base-font-size); }

$font-10px: 1em/1.1em;
$font-11px: 1.1em/1.1em;
$font-12px: 12em/11em;


.x10 { font-size: #{$font-10px}px; }
.x11 { font-size: #{$font-11px}px; }
.x12 { font-size: #{$font-12px}px; }
```

Result:

```
.x10 {
   font-size: 0.90909px;
}
.x11 {
   font-size: 1px;
}
.x12 {
   font-size: 1.09091px;
}
```

Since you mentioned accessability in the SA talk, I recommend that you add one of the mixins in this [blog post by Hugo Giraudel](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/03/18/ultimate-rem-mixin/)  to your project to allow the use REM units while also providing backwards compatibility for older browsers.

Comment: This answer adds nothing over the existing answer.  This is also a highly inappropriate way of turning an integer into a length.

Comment: @Cimmanon, your answer didn't cover broader cases where a variable is being divided by a variable. This answer covered all cases. Efficiency isn't important since SASS is precompiled into the same CSS either way.